# When we specify "--algorithms=sgd" in vw-hyperopt, does it run with adaptive, normalised and invariant updates?

Tags: vowpalwabbit, hyperopt

the confusion is because when we specify --sgd in vw command line, it runs classic sgd, without adaptive, normalised and invariant updates. So, when we specify algorithm as sgd in vw-hyperopt, does it run as classic or with special updates? Is it mandatory to specify algorithm in vw-hyperopt? Which is the default algorithm? Thank you.

Comment: Found some comments here - https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/pull/867


"sgd converts not to --sgd, but to default algorithm with AdaGrad etc."


"Omitting --algorithms is equivalent to writing --algorithms=[sgd]."



So that mostly answers the questions I had, However I would love some confirmation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-hyperopt.py) confirms that the meaning of `--algorithm sgd` here simply leaves the default alone.

This is different than `vw --sgd`. It doesn't disable the defaults by passing `--sgd` to `vw`.  IOW: yes, the adaptive, normalized and invariant updates will still be in effect.

Also: you can verify this further by looking at the log file created by `vw-hyperopt` in the current dir and verify it has no `--sgd` option in it. This log includes the full `vw` command line it executes for training and testing, e.g:

```
2020-09-08 00:58:45,053 INFO  [root/vw-hyperopt:239]: executing the following command (training): vw -d mydata.train -f ./current.model --holdout_off -c ... --loss_function quantile
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming @arielf.
You are right, I could have verified it from the log file command line itself.